# Nuget installing debian package into .NET framework 4.6.1 project; Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I have a project and whenever I perform a nuget update it fails with the following:

```
15:47:27
    Successfully installed 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 3.1.0' to MyProject.csproj
15:47:27
    WARNING: Install failed. Rolling back...
15:47:27
    WARNING: Package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3' does not exist in project 'MyProject.csproj'
15:47:27
    Removed package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 3.1.0' from 'packages.config'
```

Is anyone able to provide clarification on why it is trying to install a debian package? I looked at the dependencies for https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Targets/

It appears there are none(?)

Thanks in advance
Mark

Comment: It is quite strange,try to close VS Instance, or if it does not work, please delete `C:\Users\xxx(current use account)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config` file or then restart VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Nuget installing debian package into .NET framework 4.6.1 project;
> Why?

**Actually**, that package does not have a dependency called `runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3` and I am also wonder why your net framework project needs that dependency.

**Also**, I found that Net Framework project cannot install that package since it is not compatible with Net Framework. Please check whether your project has any dependent projects.

It is quite strange and I think that something has broken in Nuget,VS or your project itself.

**Suggestion**

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Tools**-->**Extensions and Updates** in case some extensions cause this abnormal behavior.

**2)** click [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**General**

**3)** Close VS, delete `Nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\AppData\Roaming\Nuget`,also check whether you have a new `nuget.config` file on your project parent directory or higher.

**4)** delete `.vs` hidden folder under solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder and then run `update-package -reinstall` on **Package Manager Console**(**Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manger** to reinstall every nuget packages.

**5)** run **Developer Command Prompt for VS2017** as **Administrator** and then type:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VsLangproj.olb"
```

Make sure that the file exists under the path. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/known-issues#error-installing-packages-with-nuget-27).

**6)** [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in VS Installer or update it to the latest version.

I suggest you could try every step above and give us any feedback about it.